# Wrong object_name and definition relationship in sys.sql_modules and sys.objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I ran the following query

```
SELECT sm.object_id,
       v1.object_name,
       o.type,
       o.type_desc,
       sm.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules sm
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id))) v1 (object_name)
     JOIN sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id;
```

And there are three objects with a wrong relation between `object_name` and `definition`. There is no match, no correspondence between the name and the definition it references.

[image]

It looks like this tables didn't track the delete or changes in name and definitions of these three objects.

How can this situation can be given?
How can I "update" this tables or fix this properly?

[image: Query results updated]

Comment: FYI, a single backtick (`\` `) character is needed for inline code. When pasting code blocks either wrap the **entire** code in 3 backticks(`\`\`\` `) or indent the whole block. That will format your code block as a code block.

Comment: Try running an `sp_refreshsqlmodule` over each of these to see if that changes anything.

Comment: All objects are views. Views require sp_refreshview after changes to the underlying tables.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried both sp, none of them fixed it. I hope nothing went wrong executing them... I dont know what to do.

Comment: Can you include the contents of `o.name` for the record, and also join additional on `sys.schemas` for the schema name? This should match what's in `sys.sql_modules`. Also, which of these pieces of information is correct -- the `object_name`, the `definition`, or possibly both (in the sense that, say, both `v_PendingCRMErrorsByPackage` and `AuditLog.PendingCRMErrorsByPackage` exist)? Also, do the results of (say )`OBJECT_NAME(597577167)` and `OBJECT_DEFINITION(597577167)` have a direct (mis)match?

Comment: @JeroenMostert o.name its the same as object_name. Its all NULLs in  `sm.principal_id` so I can't JOIN with `sys.schemas` (if that is the key for the ON clause).  The correct information is the object_name. Object_definition would wrong, old definition. `OBJECT_NAME(597577167)` and `OBJECT_DEFINITION(597577167)` have a direct mismatch. Thing is.. when I browse the object in SSMS and I right click onto it and I script the definition (CREATE or ALTER) it gives me the right definition.

Comment: No, the key is `objects.schema_id`. FWIW, SSMS also just uses `sys.sql_modules` to get the definition (albeit with a much more complicated query; essentially it joins `sys.all_views` to `sys.sql_modules` and matches `all_views.name` and `all_views.schema_id`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fixed the JOIN, `sys.schemas.name` matches the one of the `definition`. I dont understand you answer: you say sys.sql_modules is a alternative, more complicated way of SSMS to get object defintions?

Comment: No, I'm saying SSMS isn't magic (it has no special API to SQL Server to fetch these things, or something) and also just uses `sys.sql_modules`, so if it manages to cough up the correct definition while your query does not that's very interesting. If case you want to see the SSMS query for yourself, hook up a Profiler and filter `RPC:Starting` events with the statement text including `%ReturnsViewMetadata%`. The query is too long to be included in a comment.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your help, led me to know a bit better SQL Server/SSMS.

Comment: Me as well -- I wasn't aware `sp_rename` silently broke definitions *or* that SSMS apparently takes it upon itself to compensate for this in the background with some string replacement magic! What a cad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a side effect of using "sp_rename".
These objects will work fine, but to refresh their definitions you need to recreate them.

From [sp_rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation:

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not
>   change the name of the corresponding object either in the definition
>   column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view or obtained using the
>   OBJECT_DEFINITION built-in function. Therefore, we recommend that
>   sp_rename not be used to rename these object types. Instead, drop and
>   re-create the object with its new name.

Comment: I just checked, if you rename a view from UI, SSMS will use sp_rename and leave old name in the sql_modules. I bet when you script object, it will replace the name after loading from sql_modules or generate whole script from scratch.

Comment: Seems that the definition itself, aside from the name, is correct and up-to-date, what its no ok is the 'name' of the object written in `definition` attribute. Thanks for the answer, I guess it will become a new best practice: do not rename, drop and create... Although it sounds like something SQL Server team should fix, doesnt it?