# How can I get the definition of a view with the correct name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with several views that have been manually renamed by users in the past.

If I try to get the definition of the view so that I can script its creation elsewhere, [the name comes out wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949317/wrong-object-name-and-definition-relationship-in-sys-sql-modules-and-sys-objects). I can get a list of databases with "wrong" names behind-the-scenes using:

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE convert(nvarchar(200),definition) not like ('%'+OBJECT_NAME(object_id)+'%')
```

[image]

Is there any way to get the *correct* definition of the view, in that it will generate the view with the new name? Alternatively, is there a way to extract the behind-the-scenes name of the view so that I can `replace` it with the correct name in the definition before using it?

---

What's really annoying is that if I use the GUI to "Script View as > CREATE to > New Query Editor Window" it results in the correct CREATE script, so SSMS obviously has some way of getting access to this information:

[image]

Comment: Try dropping the views and recreating them.  I think this is a bug with renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the correct definition of the view, in that it will generate the view with the new name?

Yes.  Use [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver15) (in code or PowerShell) or SSMS (which uses SMO) to script the view.  SMO is the full-fidelity scripting engine for all SQL Server objects.

With Powershell you can automate this easilly, eg:

```
$sql = Get-SqlInstance -ServerInstance "localhost"
$db = $sql | get-sqldatabase -Name "AdventureWorks2017"
foreach ($v in $db.Views)
{
   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.View] $vv = $v
   write-host $vv.Script()
}
```

And from Profiler, there's no server-side functionality at work here.  SMO fetches the view definition, and has a TSQL parser so it can fix the DDL while scripting the object.  Here's the query SMO runs to get the view body:

```
SELECT
CAST(
        serverproperty(N''Servername'')
       AS sysname) AS [Server_Name],
db_name() AS [Database_Name],
SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) AS [Schema],
v.name AS [Name],
CAST(ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(v.object_id,N''ExecIsQuotedIdentOn''),0) AS bit) AS [QuotedIdentifierStatus],
CAST(
 case 
    when v.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
    when (
        select 
            major_id 
        from 
            sys.extended_properties 
        where 
            major_id = v.object_id and 
            minor_id = 0 and 
            class = 1 and 
            name = N''microsoft_database_tools_support'') 
        is not null then 1
    else 0
end          
             AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
CAST(ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(v.object_id,N''ExecIsAnsiNullsOn''),0) AS bit) AS [AnsiNullsStatus],
v.object_id AS [ID],
NULL AS [Text],
ISNULL(smv.definition, ssmv.definition) AS [Definition]
FROM
sys.all_views AS v
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smv ON smv.object_id = v.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS ssmv ON ssmv.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE
(v.type = @_msparam_0)and(v.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id)=@_msparam_2)
ORDER BY
[Database_Name] ASC,[Schema] ASC,[Name] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this can be done procedurally? It implied goal here is that I want to automate it, not take manual steps using the GUI.